# Printing List within dictionary horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my current code:

```
    def print_banner(input_text, horiz_vert, letters):
    '''prints string into ascii art.'''
    #Prints Horizontal 
    if horiz_vert == "horizontal":
        for i in input_text:
            for j in range(6):
                print(letters[i][j], end = "")
            print()


    #Prints Vertical 
    elif horiz_vert == "vertical":
        for i in input_text:
            for j in range(6):
                print(letters[i][j])
            print()


def main():
    # Input text to be changed into ascii art.
    input_text = input("Input your string of text here: ").lower()
    # Chooses horizontal or vertical.
    horiz_vert = input("Would you like horizontal or vertical? ").lower()
    # Dictonary with all the accii art letters
    letters = {"a": ["     ___ ",
                     "    /   \ ",
                     "   /  ^  \ ",
                     "  /  /_\  \ ",
                     " /  _____  \ ",
                     "/__/     \__\ "],
               "b": [".______ ",
                     "|   _  \ ",
                     "|  |_)  | ",
                     "|   _  < ",
                     "|  |_)  |",
                     "|______/ "]}

    print_banner(input_text, horiz_vert, letters)


# Calls Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

currently if you type in "ab" for the input_text and do a vertical print option you'll get the following output:

```
     ___ 
    /   \ 
   /  ^  \ 
  /  /_\  \ 
 /  _____  \ 
/__/     \__\ 

.______ 
|   _  \ 
|  |_)  | 
|   _  < 
|  |_)  |
|______/
```

But when you type horizontal I want to get the following output:

```
     ___         .______ 
    /   \        |   _  \ 
   /  ^  \       |  |_)  |    
  /  /_\  \      |   _  < 
 /  _____  \     |  |_)  |
/__/     \__\    |______/
```

What should I be doing to the loop to have it print like that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mainly you have to switch the `i` and `j` loops and maybe add some space

Comment: Work of art, man.

Comment: It would probably help if you made every row of the ascii-art letters the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Just switch the `for-loops`:

```
...
if horiz_vert == "horizontal":
        for j in range(6):
            for i in input_text:
                print(letters[i][j], end = "")
            print()
...
```

**why?**

Your code was `looping` through each letter in `input_text` and for each letter, you were `printing` the `rows` without a `new-line` character.

That was the right idea the two letters would just `print` out in two long lines whereas what you want is them side-by-side on the same lines.

The way you need `print` the same `row` from each letter (on the same line) and then a `new-line` (to move down for the second `row` of the letters).

To do this, we need to loop through the `rows` and for each `row`, loop through the `letters` in `input_text`. And for each letter, print that `row` with no `new-line` character. Finally, at the end of `printing` one `row`, we `print` a `new-line` to move to the next `row` with `print()`.

### Update:

From @MohitC's response, I realise there will be a problem due to how the `letters` are defined in the `dictionary`.

You have defined them so that the `string` in each `row` of a letter can be any `length`. This is fine for `printing` them `vertically`, but when `printing` them `horizontally`, this will mean they will be offset.

To fix this is *really* easy. We could go through adding `spaces` to the end of each `row` for each `letter`, but say you already had all `26` letters defined, this would be incredibly tedious.

To do this much more simply, we can use [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust). This allows us to add the right number of `spaces` to the right of a `string` to make it a certain `length`:

E.g.

```
"abc".ljust(10)
```

is

```
"abc       "
```

so we can add this into the code so that when we `print` the `row` for each `letter`, we make sure that the `row` is a certain `length` (with `ljust`). So for simplicity, I will adjust all the `rows` to `length` `15` (this is just the `length` of the longest row in the `'A'` character):

```
...
if horiz_vert == "horizontal":
        for j in range(6):
            for i in input_text:
                print(letters[i][j].ljust(15), end = "")
            print()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need all your list strings to be of even size for a particular character:

```
letters = {"a": ["     ___      ",
                 "    /   \     ",
                 "   /  ^  \    ",
                 "  /  /_\  \   ",
                 " /  _____  \  ",
                 "/__/     \__\ "],
           "b": [".______   ",
                 "|   _  \  ",
                 "|  |_)  | ",
                 "|   _  <  ",
                 "|  |_)  | ",
                 "|______/  "]}
```

Then your code for looping:

```
if horiz_vert == "horizontal":
    for j in range(6):
        for i in input_text:
            print(letters[i][j], end = "")
        print()
```

Output:

```
Input your string of text here: ab
Would you like horizontal or vertical? horizontal
     ___      .______   
    /   \     |   _  \  
   /  ^  \    |  |_)  | 
  /  /_\  \   |   _  <  
 /  _____  \  |  |_)  | 
/__/     \__\ |______/
```